# Why doesn't this list throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Given the following class structure:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

And creating a list using generics only on the initialization and not on the reference:

```
List dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Why doesn't this code generate a ClassCastException?

```
dogs.add(new Cat()); // How is Cat casted to Dog??!
Cat cat = (Cat) dogs.get(0); // Return perfectly valid Cat object.
```

I understand that there will be no compilation error since the `list` reference does not have any generics and will accept any `Object`. But why doesn't the JVM generate any exception when I try to add a Cat object?

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime. Generics are a compilation feature. Since as you said, your list is a raw list you can add any object into. _"I understand that there will be no compilation error since the list reference does not have any generics"_ you said it. You add a cat and then you get a cat at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dogs` variable is of type `List` which is a *raw* type. It is **not** of type `List<Dog>`.

And since it is a raw type, you can add any object to it. Your `Cat` instance is not casted to anything.

Generics only provide compile-time safety and check, they are not used at runtime.

Read more about raw types in the [Java Language Specification 4.8. Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8).

Comment: But the list is initialized with an object of type List<Dog>, shouldn't that throw any Exception?

Comment: The list is initialized with an object of type `List`. Only the compiler knows that the static type of the instance creation expression was  `List<Dog>`. That is in no way reflected at runtime.

Comment: @Suyash No, because the generic type is just a compile type check, at runtime there is no difference between `List<Object>` and `List<Dog>`. What you get is just a compile-time warning for using raw type.

Comment: @icza in general, generics *do* involve casting.

Answer (score 1):

For the compiler, `List dogs` is equivalent to `List<Object> dogs` so the compiler accepts adding instances of any type.

Note that the type of the list considered by the compiler is the raw type `List` (the type of the *local variable* on the left-hand side of the assignment), even if the right-hand side creates an instance of the generic type with the `Dog` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not retained at run time. So an `ArrayList<Dog>` is just an`ArrayList`. That's why no exception can be thrown at run time. The compiler could have caught this error at compile time if you haven't used a raw type `List`.